# How can I debug why safari is so slow loading a page sometimes?

Tags: http, mac, performance, safari, debug

On Mac OS X 10.6.4 with Safari 5.0.1 I entered a web address in the browser bar and sometimes it's lighting fast, and sometimes terribly slow.  My wifi connection has a perfect signal strength and the router is a cable modem from Time Warner.

I want to find out exactly where the bottle neck is when a page is loading slow so I can then fix that problem.  This isn't a case where the site I'm connecting to happens to have a lot traffic that day and it's just slow, this is a recurring problem with this mac and this wifi connection.  Often if I just quit Safari and re-launch it the same URL will load very quickly.

What tool can I run to basically see the http call in debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the timeline of web inspector. First turn on the Develop menu (Preferences... Advanced... Show develop menu in menu bar) Then choose **Show inspector** on the new Develop menu... Click on **Timeline**... Click on **record** (the black dot in the bottom left of the screen)

You should now get all kinds of timing.

However, I suspect the culprit may be your DNS server. Try changing it to [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com). [Here's some instructions](https://store.opendns.com/setup/operatingsystem/apple-osx-leopard) on how to change it.

Comment: thanks, I was trying to change my DNS servers via the web interface to the router but there was no option.  Didn't realize I should just change the DNS directly on this mac.  It's working great now, thanks!

Comment: @Andrew - You're welcome, happy to help.